# Microsoft Live Connect, REST Access Issue

Tags: liveconnect

I'm trying to access Microsoft LiveConnect from a Java webapp. And I have a problem of getting tokens.

The problem is following: I followed the **Authorization code grant flow** as indicated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx#authcodegrant

LiveConnect does redirect user-agent (browser) to my server with a URL of the following format

```
http://contoso.com/Callback.htm?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
```

then my web-app issues a REST (POST request) to LiveConnect with the following format

```
POST https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf

Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Instead of returning some meaningful data, LiveConnect return a html page contains some irrelevant information, like this

```
<html>
...
<body class="modern" onLoad="BodyLoad()">
<div class="header" id="i0272"><span>Microsoft account</span></div>
<div class="content">
<div style="padding:15px 0 0 0;font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</div>
<h1 class="css0046">We're unable to complete your request</h1>

<p class="css0005">Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.</p></div>
```

I also post here the Java code that involves with the REST api

```
    URL urlConnection = new URL(this.url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setReadTimeout(DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + data.getBytes("UTF-8").length);

        for(String key : params.keySet()){
            connection.setRequestProperty(key, params.get(key));
        }

        executed.set(true);

        connection.connect();

        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

        //outputStream.write("\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));

        outputStream.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        outputStream.flush();

        httpInputStream = connection.getResponseCode() != HTTP_OK ?
                connection.getErrorStream() :
                connection.getInputStream();

        return new Response(connection.getResponseCode(),    Utils.fromInputStream(httpInputStream));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Url of the page with your duff content might be more meaningful. Mine has this:

```
https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=2057#error=invalid_request&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20%27redirect_uri%27%20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20expected%20value%20is%20%27https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf%27%20or%20a%20URL%20which%20matches%20the%20redirect%20URI%20registered%20for%20this%20client%20application.&state=redirect_type%3dauth%26display%3dpage%26request_ts%3d1412608929255%26response_method%3dcookie%26secure_cookie%3dfalse
```

Make sure that your app and the OneDrive Dev Center Redirect URLs both have exactly the same url, ie:

> `http://contoso.com/Callback.htm`

which includes the page.

I got the same bland error page, with the URL above, when my URL in OneDrive Dev Center did not include the page.
Set the redirect URL in :

```
https://account.live.com/developers/applications
```

Log in and got to the Dashboard > My Apps > YourAppName > API Settings

When developing you also need to redirect the domain (contoso.com) to your local IIS IP address (127.0.0.1) as described here:
"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826547.aspx"

Hope this helps someone (I know it is rather late)